# Elixir: Redix package does not work with SSL on CentOS 7

Tags: ssl, redis, elixir, stunnel

I setup Redis 5.x with stunnel to accept SSL connections from client. The setup is pretty straightforward, and I just follow the instruction from Redis site.

It is something like: stunnel accepts client requests via SSL connection and forward to redis via non-SSL connection.

On 2 of my dev computers both running Mac OS X, the setup works fine with Ruby gem redis and Elixir Redix library.

The commands are as following:

Ruby:

```rb
redis = Redis.new(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6380, db: 3, ssl: true, password: 'SomeSecret :)')

redis.ping
```

Elixir:

```
{:ok, conn} = Redix.start_link( host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6380, ssl: true, password: "SomeSecret :)", socket_opts: [verify: :verify_none])

Redix.command(conn, ["PING"])
```

So I know that the redis + stunnel setup works well on 2 different Mac machines.

When I deploy the same setup to a Linux machine that run CentOS 7, the Ruby client still works fine.

However, on CentOS 7, the Elixir Redix stops working, and I get the error:

```
{:error, %Redix.ConnectionError{reason: :closed}}
```

To me, it doesn't make any sense, because the Cent OS has stunnel + redis setup is exactly the same as my 2 dev Mac machines. And the Ruby client works well on all 3 machines : 2 Mac and 1 CentOS.

However, **Elixir Redix works only on the 2 Mac machines, but not on the Cent OS**. Same setup, same code.

#### Question: Why doesn't Elixir Redix SSL code work on CentOS, while it works on Mac?

(Same setup, same code)

More information: On both Mac machines and on CentOS machine, I have:

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4.3] [source] [64-bit]
Elixir 1.9.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)
```

I just discover that on CentOS, in the log, there is an error:

```
TLS client: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:182 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Protocol Version
```

Maybe that is the problem. But I don't see it on Mac machines.

Comment: “I don't see it on Mac machines”—Macs never have had reliable up-to-date support for modern TLS, so I am not surprised. It’s hardly an OS ready for development in general.

Answer (score 1):

Given the line number in the error message, we can see that the error comes from [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-22.0.4/lib/ssl/src/tls_handshake.erl#L182).  Thus, this error is what we get if `tls_record:is_acceptable_version` returns false, which means that stunnel is suggesting a TLS version that the Elixir client doesn't want to use.

You could check which TLS versions the Elixir client is prepared to use by adding this line just before the `Redix.start_link` call:

```
IO.inspect(:ssl.versions())
```

And you could use Wireshark and capture traffic going to port 6380 on the loopback interface, to see which TLS version stunnel wants to use - it's one of the fields in the "Server Hello" message.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly on point. I just discovered it this morning and about to post a self-answer for it :)